# Boxpot shows result like a stripchart?

Tags: r, boxplot, stripchart

I want to plot a column with over 30.000 records using Boxpot. The data range is various (from 0 to 1500000). I got the result like this:

[image]

Why it doens't show the boxplot? It looks like a stripchart to me. How to show the boxplot (with median, etc.)?

Here the code I used:

```
png("time.png")
boxplot(df$time, main="Box plot of session duration", ylab="seconds")
dev.off()
```

Comment: It may be due to the scaling. Your outliers seem to be orders of magnitude higher than your median. You could test with log scale

Comment: It does show the box but it's so thin that you see it as a flat line on the bottom. You could try a log-scale using `boxplot(df$time, main="Box plot of session duration", ylab="seconds", log = "y")`

Comment: Don't plot so many values. Decide what's useful to see - a sudomain, perhaps, or clump the data.

Comment: Log scale shows the box, but I think I should pre-process the data somehow.